# what are the new BI Capabilities sharepoint 2016 has compared to sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, 2016, bi

what are the new BI Capabilities sharepoint 2016 has compared to sharepoint 2013
as the prospect of Performancepoint services,excel services and sql server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing i know.Excel Service is now not part of SharePoint 2016 core rather it is now part of Office Online server.

Read this
https://blogs.office.com/2016/11/21/updates-for-excel-services-and-bi-in-sharepoint-2016-on-premises/

Also read this for feature comparison:
http://www.epcgroup.net/business-intelligence-capabilities-SharePoint%202013.php

http://sharepointpromag.com/sharepoint/sharepoint-2016-and-sql-2016-business-intelligence